# Problemas al asignar un xml como background de un botón dentro de un fragment

Tags: android-studio, xml

estoy intentando asignar un background creado en un xml dentro de la carpeta drawable a un botón dentro de un fragment. Este es el xml del fragment y el botón es "btnSearchPartnership":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/game_background"
    tools:context=".view.fragments.PartnershipFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtSearchPartnership"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/radius_corner_white"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSearchPartnership"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/radius_corner_button"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="BUSCAR GRUPOS"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerPartnerships"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"/>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Asigno el siguiente xml radius_corner_button.xml que está en drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <!-- Si queremos añadir algún padding -->
    <padding
        android:left="4dp"
        android:top="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:bottom="4dp"    >
    </padding>

    <!-- Aquí indicamos el radio a aplicar a las esquinas -->
    <corners
        android:radius="10dp"   >
    </corners>

    <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#5D8C65" android:endColor="#003208" />

</shape>
```

Al intentar ejecutar el programa, no se le está asignando este estilo. Sin embargo, si asigno este background a un botón en una actividad, sí que le está realizando el cambio de comportamiento.

Seguro que me dejo algo, pero no sé que es...

Comment: Hola, no tiene que existir ninguna diferencia, revisa si no tienes otro archivo : radius_corner_button.xml en otra localidad

Comment: Estoy seguro que debe ser una tontería, porque si copio ese button y lo saco fuera del fragment, me funciona perfectamente. También he mirado lo que comentabas, de que no hubiera otro archivo con el mismo nombre y nada... Y si convierto ese Button a TextView, también coge el cambio de color

Answer (score 0):

Tanto el botòn de tu `Activity` como el de tu `Fragment` no deben tener problema para cargar el `Shape` y modificar el estilo de tu botòn, debes asegurar que solo tienes un archivo `radius_corner_button.xml` dentro del directorio `/drawable` para poder cargar sin problema el estilo.

```
         <Button
            ...
            ...
            ...
            android:background="@drawable/radius_corner_button"
            ...
            ...
            ...
            />
```

Tambièn puedes tratar de cargarlo programaticamente usando el mètodo setBackground() del botòn:

```
myButton.setBackground(R.drawable.radius_corner_button);
```